# How do I use a Firebase refresh token to persist authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, refresh-token

I have been trying to figure this out for weeks and either can't seem to understand the documentation, or something. I appreciate any help you can give.

I am using the Firebase SDK

I have my server-side route, in which I can access the token and could send it to the front:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
admin.initializeApp()

exports.loginRoute = (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    const { valid, errors } = validateLoginData(user)

    if (!valid) {
        return res.status(400).json(errors)
    }

    admin
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data.user.refreshToken, "refresh token")
            return data.user.getIdToken(true)
        })
        .then((token) => {
            return res.json({ token })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
            if (err.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
                return res.status(400).json({ general: "User not found" })
            } else if (err.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
                return res
                    .status(400)
                    .json({ password: "User credentials don't match" })
            } else {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: "Something went wrong, please try again."
                })
            }
        })
}
```

Here is where I could use the refresh token (on the front end) to fetch a new authentication token, but I can't figure out how to create a route to do this:

```
if (token) {
        const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token)
        if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
            localStorage.setItem("Authentication", false)
    //axios request to persist authentication would go here
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have a route that would work, or advice on what to do?

EDIT

```
const login = async (credentials) => {
        let token
        await axios
            .post("/api/login", credentials)
            .then((res) => {
                token = res.data.token
                const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${token}`
                localStorage.setItem("token", token)
                localStorage.setItem("FBIdToken", FBIdToken)
                localStorage.setItem("Authentication", true)
                context.setAuthenticated((prev) => true)
            })
            .then(() => {
                context.getUserData()
            })
            .then(() => {
                context.setUserState((prevUserState) => ({
                    ...prevUserState,
                    token
                }))
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                context.setUserErrors((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    errors: err.response.data
                }))
            })
        history.push("/")
    }
```

Observer (client-side):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
                .then((idToken) => {
                    const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${idToken}`
                    localStorage.setItem("FBIdToken", FBIdToken)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem("FBIdToken")
        }
    })
```

Comment: The Firebase Authentication JavaScript SDK already persists the user's sign-in state, and tries to restore it when you reload the page. You shouldn't have to do anything for that yourself. Is that not working for you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It is not working, my token expires after 1 hour and then I have to log out and log back in.

Comment: ID tokens for all built-in provider expire after an hour, so that makes sense. But the SDK auto-refreshes the token before that happens, so you should be able to always get a valid token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken Are you caching this token somewhere by any chance?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I believe just in the the function above. I then return it to the front when calling the login function I just edited into the post.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time parsing the use-case here. The `signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)` is supposed to be run on the client, and not on the server. Are you really using this on your server? If so, why don't you use this SDK on the client, or use the Admin SDK on the server to mint tokens?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I suppose I just haven't been coding long enough and am confused. I realized the code was slightly confusing, so I changed it to reflect the SDK I am using. The ```signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)``` is indeed on the server currently.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I am totally refactoring. I have decided to use the AuthUI and the above observer.

Will this token continue to refresh and persist the user/FBIdToken in local storage? Also, will this stay updated as long as the user doesn't clear the site data? The use case is for a PWA, and I want to ensure that when they open the app their token is still valid. Thank you for all of the help!

Comment: If you sign in on the client with the Firebase Authentication SDK, then the token should refresh automatically. You can monitor that with https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged, to merely ensure the restore of their session is picked up, use `onAuthStateChanged` instead as shown in the first example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are very helpful, thank you so much. I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.    I'll see if I can capture this thread in an answer, so that we can also get closure on the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you, still getting used to stack. I appreciate the help and mentorship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sign in with the Firebase Authentication JavaScript SDK in the client-side code, it already persists the user's sign-in state, and tries to restore it when you reload the page. You shouldn't have to do anything for that yourself.

It seems like you were using the same SDK in a server-side environment though, which is quite unusual. If you want to mint tokens yourself in a server-side environment, you should use the Firebase Admin SDK to do so. You can then send that token back to the client, and use it to sign in to Firebase Authentication there.

But for the vast majority of use-cases, I recommend using the Firebase Authentication SDK in your client-side code, so that the SDK managed refreshing of the token for you. If you then want to pass the token to the server, you can use `getIdToken()` as you do now. You can also [monitor ID token generation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth#authonidtokenchanged), or more commonly monitor if a user's sign-in session is restored as shown in the first example of the documentation on [detecting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: your first link seems to be broken, I believe this is the right one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth#authonidtokenchanged

Comment: Good catch! I updated the llink in the post. 